# check if object is a binary tree in prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

There is a task for prolog that sounds like this:
write an istree predicate that returns true only if its argument is a binary tree.
Example:

`?- istree(t(a,t(b,nil,nil),nil)).`
Returns yes

`?- istree(t(a,t(b,nil,nil))).`
Returns no

I tried to make my own code and stopped at this version:

```
domains
tree = nil; t(symbol, tree, tree).

predicates
istree(tree).
isleaf(tree).

clauses
istree(nil).
istree(t(_, Left, Right)) :-
istree(Left),
istree(Right).
isleaf(t(_, nil, nil)).

goal
%istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil), nil)).
istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil))).
```

Now, when I trying to enter the second line from the example (`istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil))).`), I get an error: `E;Test_Goal, pos: 246, 507 Type error: Wrong number of arguments`

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have here `t(a, ...)` so it is missing a further argument. Also unclear what `\_` means.

Comment: @false I apologize, `\_` is a typo. About t(a, ...) - can you please tell me how to fix the code so that in the second case it outputs "No" to the console instead of an error? We were badly told this material at university and now I don't know how to do this task :(

Comment: I referred to you entering `istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil))).` which most probably should read `istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil), nil)).`

Comment: @false In this task as an example it is specified that when `istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil), nil)).` is entered, it should output "yes", but when `istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil, nil))` is entered, it should output "No". I got output for "yes" case, but instead of "No" I get an error on insufficient number of arguments.

Comment: Then, the Prolog system you are using which is (non-standard) Turbo-/PDC Prolog and the exercises (which apparently assume ISO Prolog) are just out of sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define second argument "tree" as empty
Here is example: `istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil), empty)).`

```
domains
tree = nil; t(symbol, tree, tree); empty().

predicates
istree(tree).

clauses
istree(nil).
istree(t(_, L, R)) :- istree(L), istree(R).

goal
istree(t(a, t(b, nil, nil), empty)).
```